# In Ember.js, ID of the sub-array elements are not passed within ajax put

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I do a `put` call in `ember.js` and I am passing an object which contains an array. The element's id in this array are never passed to the backend, yet they do exist in the object.

I do a `put` call using

```
this.ajax.put('path', { data: object }.then();
```

The object that I am passing as the data has an array (example of the DTO).

```
object = {
  "array": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "prop1",
      "prop2",
      "etc..."
    }
  ],
  "prop1",
  "prop2",
  "etc..."
}
```

The way that I construct each object from the array is by using

```
let objectArray = get(object, 'array');
let elementInObjectArray = //ajax call to get the element to add;
objectArray.pushObject(store.createRecord('element-in-object-array', { 
   id: elementInObjectArray.id,
   prop1: elementInObjectArray.prop1,
   etc...
})
```

Just before my `put` call, I log the `id` of the `object.array.element.id`, and they are defined and accessible (as string). (See image)

[image]

Yet, this `id` is never passed to the backend, and then I get a `404` from the server because the id is the primarykey. (See image of my `put` `request payload`)

[image]

I know that ember always return a `string` as an `id` when creating a record, but I don't think this is the reason why it fails since I would probably get more like a 400 for bad formatting. Right now, the `id` is just never passed.

How can I make sure that the id of the array element is passed in the call?

Comment: `let elementInObjectArray = //ajax call to get the element to add;` - you need to write ajax response success function to assign the ajax result for `elementInObjectArray` and use `pushObject` to add.

Comment: @EmberFreak Thanks for the comment. Sorry I am not following. Are you saying to do the `pushObject` in the `.then()` of the ajax call for `elementInObjectArray`?

Comment: Yes. you are right.